# Stripe V3 Cardholder name on source card

Tags: javascript, c#, stripe-payments, stripes

I have MVC project and facing one issue with stripe flow. any help would be really appreciated.

Below is my flow.

- I'm creating card token from UI using stripe js version v3. with this code, I'm able to retrieve both card and token perfectly from stripe.

  ```
  stripe.createToken(card, { name: name }).then(function (result) {
   if (result.error) {
       // Inform the customer that there was an error.           
   } else {
     // stripeTokenHandler will post the form to back end with token, here we are getting card with proper name,
     // but we are just sending token to back end
       stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
   }
  });
  ```
- Then I use that token further to create a stripe source with C# back end code, for that I have used **Stripe.net, Version=37.15.0.0**m below is the code.

  ```
  // creating a stripe customer, consider this is working fine
   Stripe.Customer customer = GetCustomerService().Create(options, requestOptions);

  // create the credit card source and attach it to the current StripeCustomerId
   var options = new Stripe.SourceCreateOptions()
   {
       Type = "card",
       Token = token,
   };

   var requestOptions = new Stripe.RequestOptions();

   if (stripeAccountId.IsNotEmpty())
       requestOptions.StripeAccount = stripeAccountId;

   Stripe.Source source = null;

   try
   {
       source = GetSourceService().Create(options, requestOptions);
   }
   catch (StripeException ex)
   {
       msgs.Add(ex.Message, MessageType.UserError, ex);
       msgs.Add($"Payment source was not created", MessageType.UserError);
   }
  ```
- And this is how I'm retrieving stripe sources.

  ```
  List<Stripe.Source>() sources = GetSourceService().List(customerId).ToList();
  ```
- This all works fine, **but the retrieved sources does not contains the name of card holder, which was there when we created and retrieved token.** I tried to look at the documentation, but no luck.
- I think it's issue in the flow, I might be missing some pieces but not sure what it is. Again, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building a net new project you should really look at using the newer [Payment Methods / Payment Intents APIs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment) instead of what you're doing here.

That said, you don't seem to be [attaching the Token to the Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-source), rather you seem to be [creating a Source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/create) - which is different.  If you do want to create the Source with a name, you'd want [to provide that](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/create#create_source-owner-name).